# Extract plain text from silverlight rich text box - LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the plain text from the xaml content of the SL 4 rich text box.
The content looks like this:

```
<Section xml:space=\"preserve\" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste=\"False\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">
    <Paragraph FontSize=\"12\" FontFamily=\"Arial\" Foreground=\"#FF000000\" FontWeight=\"Normal\" FontStyle=\"Normal\" FontStretch=\"Normal\" TextAlignment=\"Left\">
         <Run Text=\"Biggy\" />
    </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

When I try this:

```
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var Paras = root.Descendants("Paragraph");
            foreach (XElement para in Paras)
            {
                foreach (XElement run in Paras.Descendants("Run"))
                {
                    XAttribute a = run.Attribute("Text");
                    text += null != a ? (string) a : "";
                }
            }
```

Paras is empty.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any hints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the namespace in your XML when selecting elements, you can use [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx) to declare and use it - this works:

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
var Paras = root.Descendants(xmlns + "Paragraph");
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to BrokenGlass.The full function:

```
string StringFromRichTextBox(string XAML)
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Parse(XAML);
        XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var Paras = root.Descendants(xmlns + "Paragraph");            
        foreach (XElement para in Paras)
        {
            foreach (XElement run in Paras.Descendants(xmlns + "Run"))
            {
                XAttribute a = run.Attribute("Text");
                sb.Append(null != a ? (string)a : "");
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

It worked! Hope this help you.
Nguyen Minh Hien